# Entity Framework Code First - Using interfaces on domain models

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, ef-code-first, domain-driven-design

Let's say you have a Car Park, each car park hold x amount of Cars and each car can have different properties. Like this:

```
public class CarPark
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public ICollection<ICar> Cars { get; set; }
}

public interface ICar
{
    string Model { get; set; }
}

public class Volvo : ICar
{
    public string Model { get; set; }

    public string Color { get; set; }
}

public class Bmw : ICar
{
    public string Model { get; set; }

    public int Wheels { get; set; }
}
```

How do you deal with that kind of scenario when the models are different?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean how you have to deal with EF messing up the mapping of your models due to the Interface: you can manually configure the translation of your models in the OnModelCreation method of your DbContext.

Look here for more information: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, instead of using a interface you create an abstract class, i adjusted the code above to show how it's done:

```
public class CarPark
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Car> Cars { get; set; }
}

public abstract class Car
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Model { get; set; }
}

[Table("Volvo")]
public class Volvo : Car
{
    public string Color { get; set; }
}

[Table("Bmw")]
public class Bmw : Car
{
    public int Wheels { get; set; }
}
```

Because of the table annotation each car will end up in a separate table, this strategy is called TPT - Table Per Type, if the attribute is removed all cars will end up in the same table, that strategy is called TPH - Table Per Hierarchy.

The example is pretty bad but imagine each car is a payment provider with unique settings or something similar.

More info:
https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/inheritance-strategy-in-code-first.aspx